# JPA delete older records than x days and write tests for it with H2

Tags: java, jpa, junit, h2

I want to delete data that is older than x days from history table. Each row has a date field. So far I have only managed to do it with native query.

```
public interface HistoryItemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<HistoryItem, Long> {
  @Modifying
  @Query(
    nativeQuery = true,
    value = "DELETE FROM history_item hi WHERE trunc(hi.timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/HELSINKI') <= trunc(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/HELSINKI') - 7"
  )
  Integer removeOldHistoryItems();
}
```

The application itself runs on Oracle DB and there this method works fine. The tests however run H2 database and therefore I get `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException Syntax error in SQL statement "DELETE FROM HISTORY_ITEM HI WHERE TRUNC(HI.TIMESTAMP AT[*] TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/HELSINKI') <= TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/HELSINKI') - 7 "; expected "(, ., [, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, ILIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )"; SQL statement:` when tests run code that calls this method.

What can I do to be able to test it? Can this query be converted to something that does not require native query?

Answer (score 1):

`timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'time zone name'` is supported since old unsupported H2 1.4.200, it looks like you use some older version that needs to be upgraded.

Please note that IANA (Olson) time zone names are case-sensitive in H2, you need to specify it as `'Europe/Helsinki'`, otherwise you'll get an unknown time-zone ID exception.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes I have currently com.h2database:h2:1.4.197 because this project also needs org.orbisgis:h2gis-functions:1.3.2 and these versions need to be compatible with each other. I tried to use com.h2database:h2:2.1.214 with org.orbisgis:h2gis2.1.0 but now other select statements started to fail.

Comment: For example `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT [*]VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'info.BUILD_ID'"; expected "DISTINCT, ALL, *, INTERSECTS (, NOT, EXISTS, UNIQUE, INTERSECTS"; SQL statement:
SELECT VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'info.BUILD_ID' [42001-214]` But I dont even know where it comes from because  my project does not contain code with BUILD_ID.

Comment: It looks like a query from outdated version of Flyway or possibly some other library, you need to upgrade other dependencies too.

Comment: Yes. I have 5.2.4. But updating it caused other issues. Will post new thread about it and then try this answer again.